# How to truncate then append to a RAW file in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I'm attempting to pull data from several spreadsheets that reside in a single folder, then put all the data into a single csv file along with column headings.

I have a foreach loop container setup to iterate through each of the filenames in the folder, which then appends this data to a RAW file, however as many have seemed to run into, there does not appear to be a built in option that will allow one to simply truncate the RAW file before entering the loop container.

Jamie Thompson described a similar situation in his blog [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2006/06/22/SSIS_3A00_-Append-to-a-raw-file.aspx), but the links to the examples do not seem to work.  Does anyone have an easy way to truncate the RAW file in a stand alone step before entering the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2):

The approach I always use is to create a data flow with the appropriate metadata format but no actual rows and route that to a RAW file set to Create new.

In my existing data flow, I look at the metadata that populates the RAW file and then craft a select statement that mimics it.

e.g.

```
SELECT
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(70)) AS AddressLine1
,   CAST(NULL AS bigint) AS SomeBigInt
,   CAST(NULL AS nvarchar(max)) AS PerformanceLOL
```

Comment: Is there a way to do that without a database connection though?  Right now, it just takes the data from excel and dumps it into CSV with no SQL Server connections needed.

Comment: I'd read this article http://rolandholtermann.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/append-data-to-a-raw-file-using-a-for-each-loop-container-in-ssis/ that kind of talked about doing the way you describe Bill, but was hoping to not require a data connection into a database.

Comment: You could build a custom Script task that generates the necessary output.

Comment: That's a good thought N West, however is there method I could call in a script task that would just truncate the raw file and leave the metadata intact?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would did:

- Make your initial raw file
- Make a copy of that raw file
- Use a file task to replace the staging file at the beginning of your package/job every time.

In my use case I have 20 `foreach` threads writing to their own files all at the same time. No thread can create and then append, so you just "recreate" by copying over an 'empty' raw file that already has the meta data assigned, before calling the threads:

[image]